# Why Flash games' network communications is not monitored by F12 in browsers?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I was trying to track the network comms of online Flash games on websites with F12 dev tools, there were only requests for certain graphic resources but no common communications like where I moved to or what tasks I accomplished.

I wonder if there are ways I can monitor those and why they are not monitored using f12. I have trouble finding resources about Flash and ActionScript regarding this problem, so any help would be useful and appreciated.

Comment: How are you running Flash, and in what browser and what operating system? ... Maybe try using an Internet Traffic Inspection tool (sometimes called a Internet Packet Sniffer)? An external tool might pick up the internet traffic... I think it doesn't show as "network comms" in the browser software because the communication is actually done by Flash Player (as separate software). Well that would be true, _IF_ you were using the Flash plugin.

Comment: I'm running flash with chrome on windows. Yes I've tried to sniff the packets but encryption has made it meaningless. Is there a way to monitor flash network comment like monitoring http with chrome while the contents are plain text? @VC.One Thank you for your help!

Comment: Flash player used to be a plugin for browsers, and it was a separate exe file, so its traffic was initially out of scope for Chrome dev tools. Probably they won't bother now, as Flash is discontinued. I say use Wireshark to capture traffic originated from Flash apps, and probably a debugger to retrieve HTTPS session key to allow Wireshark to decrypt traffic (which could prove to be quite challenging).